# How to do scale 9 with CSS or JS with a rectangle

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I would like to have a custom CSS *border* texture around a rectangle, like hand-drawn cross-hatching for example. In theory I would create a "scale 9" slicing of the rectangle so no matter what dimensions it had it would always have the border.

[image]

Is anything like this possible purely in CSS? Or if not, then how could you accomplish this in JS? I am thinking in terms of creating a text input with an inner shadow sort of border effect around it using cross-hatching. Wondering if/how can that be done in pure CSS or if not pure CSS then in JS.

Side note, just discovered [`border-image`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-image/), not sure if that's related.

I would like to have borders look essentially along the lines of this:

[image]

Comment: I've not fully understood what kind of border you want; because usually borders and innerShadow already behave like that without any work at all. Besides that, what comes to my mind: arranging 9 Elements/like `<div>` and using `clipPath` or `background` (image, position, scale) + `overflow:hidden` something similar with SVG and `<use>` tags to copy Elements or the last resort: render it into a `canvas` each section properly scaled and positioined. Edit: nice, I knew that you could use an image for the border but wasn't aware of its capabilities.

Comment: What's your target/audiance (Browsers and versions?). A demo that only has to run on your computer, relatively modern browsers or does it include the always feared IE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `border-image` for this.

```css
#border-image {
  font-size: 20px;
  width:300px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  padding: 35px;
  margin: 2em;
  
  
  border-image-source: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='22' height='22'  viewBox='0 0 22 22'%3E%3Cpath d='M2,5 Q2,2 5,2L17,2 Q20,2 20,5L20,17 Q20,20 17,20L5,20 Q2,20 2,17Z' stroke='red' fill='none' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  border-image-slice: 5;
  border-image-repeat: round;
  border-image-width: 22px;
}

}
```

```html
<div id="border-image" class="bi">
</div>
```

For the `border-image-source` I'm using an SVG element:

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox='0 0 22 22' width='200'>
<path d='M2,5 Q2,2 5,2L17,2 Q20,2 20,5L20,17 Q20,20 17,20L5,20 Q2,20 2,17Z' stroke='red' fill='none'  />
</svg>
```

If you want to use this svg element as background you can encode it to this:

```
"data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='22' height='22'  viewBox='0 0 22 22'%3E%3Cpath d='M2,5 Q2,2 5,2L17,2 Q20,2 20,5L20,17 Q20,20 17,20L5,20 Q2,20 2,17Z' stroke='red' fill='none' /%3E%3C/svg%3E"
```

In order to encode the svg to data uri you can use this [URL-encoder for SVG](https://codepen.io/yoksel/pen/JDqvs)

The value I'm using for the `border-image-slice` is 5 since this is the size of the rounded corners.

[image: Codrops border-image]

In the previous image this would be the size of the C1, C2,C3 and C4 
The image is from this article: [border-image](https://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/border-image/)

See this in an example:

```css
svg{border:1px solid}
line{stroke:black; stroke-width:.1}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox='0 0 22 22' width='200'>
<path d='M2,5 Q2,2 5,2L17,2 Q20,2 20,5L20,17 Q20,20 17,20L5,20 Q2,20 2,17Z' stroke='red' fill='none'  />
  <g id="lines1">
  <line class="h" x1="0" x2="22" y1="5" y2="5"></line>
  <line class="h" x1="0" x2="22" y1="17" y2="17"></line>

  <line class="v" x1="5" x2="5" y1="0" y2="22"></line>
  <line class="v" x1="17" x2="17" y1="0" y2="22"></line>
</g>
</svg>
```

I'm using `border-image-width: 22px;` but of coarse you can change this:

Please read more about [border-image](https://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/border-image/)

Answer (score -1):

Hi you can use ::before & ::after Pseudo-elements for the HTML element using CSS you can apply border etc.

Comment: yes, but `:before` and `:after` are 2 additional elements. Depending on the desired result you'd need up to 8 for slice9

Comment: http://codebrief.com/2011/11/two-game-changing-css-3-features/

Check this one as well